# Spotting bots that auto upvote for their owners

Tags: discussion, voting

As a new person to so, I see some answers / comments that immediately get a vote or two after it has been made. I understand that so has x thousands of people on the site at one given time etc, but it seems a little strange that it seems to be happening to certain authors only. It seems more than a wee bit suspicious to my eyes!

imo it brings down the quality / trust of answers, and so was wondering is this a known problem for so, and what plans are being made to tackle it.

I'm sure it isn't as bad as it could be, but I'm pretty sure it's happening!

Comment: Got any evidence or even examples of accounts you suspect?

Comment: The speed of reaction at SE is amazing. Don't underestimate this, there's a good 100.000 pairs of eyes looking at you, as soon you click save.

Comment: Why did you create bots to downvote this question as soon as you posted it?

Comment: I know! It’s fishy how the people who write good answers always seem to get upvotes.

Comment: @minitech and one or two instant upvotes for the obviously bad answers?

Comment: @user3791372, again: **we need evidence** for any kind of accusation you may say.

Comment: and what pray tell is such evidence? a confession, a video of an author logging into a second account, or, just an eyeballing of it happening on the site? all but the latter evidence is impossible.

Comment: And of course by we need evidence @Kyllopardiun means don't publicly discuss specific cases of suspected voting fraud but rather report specific suspected voting fraud instances privately.

Comment: The moderators have tools that you don't, if you report the user names (better yet ids) they can check ip addresses and more info to check what you are saying **flag it to a moderator**. (You don't have to post it here)

Comment: @Kyllopardiun ok sure. lots of downvotes over a q about something that is clearly happening. welcome to meta!

Comment: there are renegades around who automatically upvote all questions from low rep users as some sort of Fight-The-System mentality.  There used to be one posting here now and then, but I think he got suspended.  I also suspect there are stupid people (I kid you not!) who upvote any question too many words they dont understand.

Comment: @user3791372 The downvotes are primarily because people *don't* feel that this is "clearly happening".  [That a post is voted on very quickly after being posted isn't evidence that the voters are bots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266302/spotting-bots-that-auto-upvote-for-their-owners#comment64922_266302).

Comment: That voting on S.O. is inconsistent I'd say is pretty obvious -- but I doubt it's because of bots or some other form of cheating.  It's how it is; questions that would get poo-pooed with one particular tag/language will get applauded with another.  But that's just people (different strokes for different folks and all).  There's also the reality of questions that get advertised in chat, on twitter, etc.  But that's still not cheating.  Like your mom hopefully told you earlier: *Life is not fair.*

Comment: They eventually get caught, the votes invalidated, and the person running the bots/puppets/voterings gets suspended.  Happens all the fuggen time.  IIRC, was at least two or three a week by the end of my term.

Comment: @Will I've never had trouble finding a sock voter, if I wanted to. And often, they make themselves obvious, without even looking. Point being: You are right! ;)

Comment: It has been suggested that some folks who frequent SO also frequent chat rooms where they alert their buddies to upvote/downvote/close certain questions/answers.  I've seen enough curious (and amazingly rapid) voting/closing to believe there may be substance to these rumors.

Comment: Not bots, but I've seen some truly horrific posts get upvotes as soon as they're posted. I'm guessing this is some friend trying to help out, or someone with multiple accounts. It often gets cancelled out with a few downvotes seconds later.

Comment: I have noticed several times for my answers, when I click add answer it was added and got immediately upvote. Definitely one could not manage read the answer in half a second but I know that It was not some second account too. It just happens sometimes. Even more one evening I thought that was some sort of system feature which upvotes users automatically if they reach some points or something like this but it is not happening as a rule.

Answer (score 16):

It is **extremely unlikely** that there are bots that auto-upvote on the site.

- First of all, such a bot would require at least 15 points before it could even vote; you cannot vote on posts as a new user. As such, bots would have to have interacted with the site beyond registering, a reasonable barrier.
- Moderators have tools to spot suspicious voting behaviour. Bots voting on their author's posts would stand out like a sore thumb. Anyone trying this will find themselves on the wrong side of the [penalty box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/).

Bots would require access to real-time information about posting to even achieve such behaviour.

They do have such access, because *all users do*. Any tag page will show you, in almost real time, when live updates occur. On the *New questions* tab you get to see when questions come in, and within seconds of the question being asked, people are looking at them. This is done through [web sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket); the site informs your browser when new questions are posted (as well as let you know you have any messages or received points).

Those same sockets also let you know about people posting answers to questions. If you have a question page open, you are notified when answers are posted, votes are cast, edits are made, or comments are added.

Taken together, this means that a) people are looking at questions early, and b) get to see answers come in *almost as they are posted*. And when an answer is posted, apparently sometimes people think those answers are good and upvotes are given. **By human beings**.

Any time you see this happening, take a look at the *leftmost* tag on the post; tags are ordered by popularity. Hover over the tag, and take a look a the number of followers; it is an indication of how many people might be interested in the question you are looking at right now. Then reload the page, and look at the *viewed* counter in side bar on the right; that's an indicator of how many people have been actively looking at this new question in a short space of time.

If both of these numbers are extremely low (< 500 people following the tag, views < 5 or so), **then** you may have reasons to be suspicious of *out of proportion* voting behaviour (more than 2 upvotes within seconds), **perhaps**. In that case, I'd look for more posts by the same author, see if there are correlations between author and other users (always answering questions by the same small group of people, perhaps). You may have found a sock-puppet, and if so, you'd flag one of the posts, pick *other* and ask a moderator to take a look. Include your evidence. If there is a sock-puppet being used, it'll be a human being using multiple accounts, not a bot.

Comment: Tldr; it happens sometimes, you may have seen it, please tell a mod. Everything you mention like post views, multiple upvotes within seconds, out of proportion votes to page views etc are what I've taken into consideration before posting this question. Sorry about not stating that, I thought it'd be obvious!

Comment: I've trashed hundreds (thousands?) of sock puppets, and I have no evidence that any of them was operated in an automated fashion. People who run sock puppets generally are pretty lazy, and wouldn't bother (or have the skills needed) to build a bot to do this. Many of them put so little effort into it that they give their sock puppet the same name as their main account. I swear some companies in certain locations [must train their employees on how to run sock puppets as part of orientation](https://twitter.com/tinkertim/status/489646169862074369), because they tend to follow the same patterns.

Comment: Where did the other answer go?

Comment: @user3791372 it was deleted by its owner.

Comment: has the owner now been banned?

Comment: @user3791372: no, they just decided to delete the post. Noone forced them, they didn't break any rules, and they certainly have not been banned.